# $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2+1})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2+1})$$

I'm completely stuck into it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** $\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2+1}=\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2+1}}$

Answer (score 5):

We can use the approximation 
$$(1+x)^\alpha\sim_0 1+\alpha x$$
then in our case we have $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$  so
\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2+1})&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}})\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(1+\frac{1}{2n}-1-\frac{1}{2n^2})=\frac{1}{2}.\end{align}

Comment: That second equality is only valid if you recognize the error in your approximation approximation is $o(n)$.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply and divide by the quantity $\sqrt{n^{2}+n} + \sqrt{n^{2}+1}$

Answer (score 1):

A useful general approach to limits is, in your scratch work, to take every complicated term and replace it with a similar approximate term.

As $n$ grows large, $\sqrt{n^2 + n}$ looks like $\sqrt{n^2} = n$. More precisely,

$$ \sqrt{n^2 + n} = n + o(n) $$

where I've used [little-o notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation). In terms of limits, this means

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + n} - n}{n} = 0 $$

but little-o notation makes it much easier to express the intuitive idea being used.

Unfortunately, $\sqrt{n^2 + 1}$ also looks like $n$. Combining these estimates,

$$ \sqrt{n^2 + n} - \sqrt{n^2 + 1} = (n + o(n)) - (n + o(n)) = o(n) $$

Unfortunately, this cancellation has clobbered all of the precision of our estimates! All this analysis reveals is

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + n} - \sqrt{n^2+1}}{n} = 0 $$

which isn't good enough to answer the problem. So, we need a better estimate.

---

A standard way to get better estimates is differential approximation. While the situation at hand is a little awkward, there is fortunately a standard trick to deal with square roots, or any power:

$$ \sqrt{n^2 + n} = n \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n}} $$

and now we can invoke differential approximation (or Taylor series)

$$ f(x+h) = f(x) + h f'(x) + o(h) $$

with $f(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}$ at $x=1$ to get

$$ \sqrt{n^2 + n} = n \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n} \right)\right)
= n + \frac{1}{2} + o(1) $$

or equivalently in limit terms,

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^2 + n} - n - \frac{1}{2} = 0$$

similarly,

$$ \sqrt{n^2 + 1} = n + o(1)$$

and we get

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^2 + n} - \sqrt{n^2 + 1}
=  \lim_{n \to \infty} (n + \frac{1}{2} + o(1)) - (n + o(1))
=  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2} + o(1) = \frac{1}{2} $$

---

If we didn't realize that trick, there are a few other tricks to do, but there is actually a straightforward way to proceed too. Initially, simply taking the Taylor series for $g(x) = \sqrt{n^2 + x}$ around $x=0$  doesn't help, because that gives

$$ g(x) = n + \frac{1}{2} \frac{x}{n} + o(x^2) $$

the Taylor series for $h(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + x}$ doesn't help either. But this is why we pay attention to the remainder term! One form of the Taylor remainder says that:

$$ g(x) = n + \frac{1}{2} \frac{x}{n} - \frac{1}{8} \left( n^2 + c \right)^{-3/2} x^2$$

for some $c$ between $0$ and $x$. It's easy to bound this error term for $x > 0$.

$$ \left| \frac{1}{8} \left( n^2 + c \right)^{-3/2} x^2 \right|
\leq  \left| \frac{1}{8} \left( n^2 \right)^{-3/2} x^2 \right|
= \left| \frac{x^2}{8 n^3} \right| $$

So, for $x > 0$,

$$ g(x) = n + \frac{1}{2} + O\left( \frac{x^2}{n^3} \right) $$

(note I've switched to big-O). Plugging in $n$ gives

$$ g(n) = n + \frac{1}{2} + O\left( \frac{1}{n} \right) $$

which gives the approximation we need (better than we need, actually). (One could, of course, simply stick to limits rather than use big-O notation)

This is not the simplest way to solve the problem, but I wanted to demonstrate a straightforward application of the tools you have learned (or will soon learn) to solve a problem in the case that you can't find a 'clever' approach.